# Is there a way to specify $GlobalRev$ in a file using Subclipse for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I know how to get the local version number into a file with Eclipse. Right click, Team, set property then svn:keywords Id.

But how do you get the $GlobalRev$ to appear? There's something called svnversion which is supposed to do this but is it integrated into Subclipse?

Answer (score 4):

Subversion does not support the concept of a $GlobalRev$ keyword.  There is a command line tool called svnversion that will output revisions to stdout.  You can combine that with a script to write this to a file.  This is asked about all the time, so there is a FAQ:

http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#version-value-in-source

If you are on Windows, there is also a command line program available called SubWCRev.exe that is similar to svnversion but will do substitution in a file for you.  Note that you cannot use this on a versioned file, you need the combine it with a template file of some kind.  See:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html

Either of these could be run from Eclipse by setting up an External Tool command for it.

Comment: Thanks. Problem is in this case I'm one temporary contractor in a big team some of which is permanent, so it's probably too much to expect everyone to add an external tool to their setups, even if that's the only solution...